# Why does JS return NaN if I compare to numbers and assign the result to a new variable?

Tags: javascript

I have trouble with handling very simple data basically. When I run the following code it returns `NaN` instead of a new number assigned to `max`.

```
let Bought = [eurBought, usdBought, jpyBought, gbpBought, cadBought, audBought, chfBought];
let Sold = [eurSold, usdSold, jpySold, gbpSold, cadSold, audSold, chfSold];

maxBought = Math.max(...Bought);
    console.log(typeof(maxBought));
// returns `number`

maxSold = Math.max(...Sold);
    console.log(typeof(maxSold));
// returns `number`

let max;

if(maxBought > maxSold) {
    max = maxBought;
} else {
    max = maxSold;
}

console.log(max)
// returns `NaN`
```

For me there is no reason why JS should return `NaN` when I push to numbers in..
I also tried to `parseFloat` `maxBought` and `maxSold` but still it returns `NaN`.

**Edit to @forgiveson comment:**

I manipulate a JSON file with several logics within an AJAX function.
I added the code for one of the arrays variables `eurBought`.

```
let resultBought = {};
let resultSold = {};

for (var i = 0; i < tradesTotal; i++) {

symbol = trades[i].fields.orderSymbol;
  // returns e.g. EUR/USD

symbolBase = symbol.slice(0, 3);
  // returns e.g. EUR

symbolCounter = symbol.slice(3, 6);
  // returns e.g. USD

lots = trades[i].fields.orderLots;
lots = Number(lots);
 // returns e.g. 1.00

orderType = trades[i].fields.orderType;
 // orderTypes 0, 2, 4 are long trades, 1, 3, 5 shorts accordingly

 // check for major pairs where XXX/YYY = defined currencies
 if (symbolBase.match(/^(EUR|GBP|AUD|CHF|JPY|USD|CAD)$/) && symbolCounter.match(/^(EUR|GBP|AUD|CHF|JPY|USD|CAD)$/)) {

 if (orderType === '0' || orderType === '2' || orderType === '4') {

 // Base currency
 if(resultBought.hasOwnProperty(symbolBase + 'VolumeBought')) {
                                resultBought[symbolBase + 'VolumeBought'] += Number(lots * 100.000);
                            }
                            else [...]
                          }
                      }

                }
                        // Update Chart.JS Trade Volume Chart with new data set here

                    var eurBought = resultBought.EURVolumeBought;
```

I will check every single variable again. Initially I thought that I work with two `numbers` so the other variables within the arrays doesn't matter anymore.

Comment: What are the values of `Bought` and `Sold`?

Comment: @forgivenson Edit: arrays of numbers. Sorry, i was referring to maxBought and maxSold

Comment: @ASDFGerte that's not true, as long as Bought and Sold are arrays of numbers, this code works as expected

Comment: @Phanti Bought and Sold should both be arrays of numbers for this to work. Eg `Bought = [1,2,3,4]`

Comment: @TKoL They are, at least indirectly.  They contain variables which are numbers themselves.

Comment: @TKoL true. I have trouble reading code, that is by itself not working, especially when reading very fast. My glass ball sometimes cannot make predictions fast enough.

Comment: You just said they aren't. The guy asked you what the values are, and you said, `1200 and 800` @Phanti

Comment: `NaN` ***is*** a `Number`.

Comment: FYI, `typeof(NaN)` returns `'number'`.

Comment: show me EXACTLY what the values of Bought and Sold are. You are giving mixed messages right now.

Comment: We still need to know what **exact** values are inside all those variables in the arrays. Given the proofs in the answers below that the code works if all the values in the arrays are numbers, it would appear that these values (or at least some of them) don't contain what you're expecting. Have you tried logging them, and/or using the debugger to trace their values after they've been assigned, and/or checking their types?

Comment: Okay, based on your update, what are the values of the new variables you added? `eurBought`, etc?

Comment: Like others are saying, one of the values in one of the arrays is not a number. `Math.max(1,2,3,4,"test") //NaN`

Comment: [I cannot reproduce this](https://jsbin.com/fexupekoke/edit?js,console)

Comment: Just console.log the values of Bought and Sold, you will probably see your problem.

Comment: Re the edit...that's only one of the multiple variables. And it still relies on variables which are not shown in the code sample. So we still cannot run it or use it to verify the source of your issue. Have you been listening to us? **YOU** need to do some basic logging and debugging, and find out **which one(s)** of the variables in those arrays does not contain a valid number. Then you need to start tracing back to where that variable was created, and see what could have happened. If you can narrow it down to one or two, then we might be able to help in more detail with that.

Comment: @Phanti I've tracked the problem down: if even one element of the Sold array is NaN, NaN will be the output of your code. Filter out the NaNs of both arrays if you don't want that to be a possible result.

Comment: @ADyson will do. Still have to read all of these comments and replies. This is way to much traffic for me as a new to verify in a couple of minutes :p

Comment: It's not the newbish-ness which is the issue, it's the lack of verifiable info and clarity in the question which causes downvotes. (e.g. absence of traceable actual data values etc which would be expected in any bug report. Or indeed, in a description of any problem with any item (compare to reporting a problem with a car, for instance - you wouldn't expect the mechanic to be able to do much if you just say "here's my car, why doesn't it work sometimes?". First thing they will do is ask for more information.)

Comment: @ADyson Got your point, agree. Anyways in fact one variable within the array was `undefined` since there was no value assigned while looping. So I at least got a solution for my problem ;) Thanks again.

Comment: Well, phanti's solution really just masks the problem. Ideally you should go and fix whatever it is which is causing the value to be undefined. Or, if that's a permissible situation, you can filter the value as suggested, and make sure you're clear what the expected result should be in that scenario (e.g. should the user be aware that one value wasn't available, or something?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code outputs 8 as expected, when Bought and Sold are arrays of numbers.

```js
Bought = [1,2,3,4];
Sold = [2,4,6,8];

maxBought = Math.max(...Bought);
    console.log(typeof(maxBought));
// returns `number`

maxSold = Math.max(...Sold);
    console.log(typeof(maxSold));
// returns `number`

let max;

if(maxBought > maxSold) {
    max = maxBought;
} else {
    max = maxSold;
}

console.log(max)
```

[edit] on the other hand, if any element of Sold is `NaN`, then your output will be `NaN`. You should consider filtering out `NaN` out of Bought and Sold before processing them

```
Bought = Bought.filter(x => !isNaN(x));
Sold = Sold.filter(x => !isNaN(x));
```

Comment: Which means problem lies elsewhere and not in the code posted.

Comment: @Salman actually, the problem is arguably with the code posted. If the first element of `Sold` is `NaN`, you get the result OP is talking about

Comment: @TKoL if you see the latest edit to the question, it's clear that the values in the arrays are actually variables which are being assigned elsewhere. So if they're being assigned incorrectly, that problem occurs outside the posted code.

Comment: @ADyson BUT, if the code is supposed to appropriately handle NaN values and not output that as the maximum, then the problem is still in the code posted

Comment: @TKoL But there's no indication that it's designed to "appropriately handle NaN", or is intended to, either. In fact, OP's wording suggests they are not expecting this to ever occur and don't understand how it's happened.

Comment: On the other hand, the fact that it does occur means that, despite his expectations, NaN CAN be in the array, and yet he still seems to desire it to not be the output.

Comment: Neither you nor I can fully know what's right or wrong, because this isn't our code. All I've done is made him aware that NaN is in the array, and how to take it out if he so chooses

Comment: @TKoL "NaN CAN be in the array" ...which almost certainly points to a bug in the code which generates the values for the array. QED. If that's fixed, and it's never possible for the numbers to be wrong, then there's no real need to handle it here. And it's not specified what the output should be in such a case, either.

Comment: "All I've done is made him aware that NaN is in the array"...which is basically a comment and a pointer to do some debugging, not an actual fix for the bug or solution to the issue. Which was Salman's point in the very first comment on your answer. I would expect that this filtering will produce undesirable / inaccurate results which don't pass test cases. There's no indication that this code is supposed to work when not all the values are present. Absence of values likely indicates a problem elsewhere.

Comment: OK, well I hope he discovers those issues and figures it out. He has the information he needs now and can choose what to do